# How to set a curly rule properly?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

I use *curly* option to a *as-needed*.

```
if (1)
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if (0) console.log(1);
else console.log(0);
```

But as you know there is a problem like in above situation, *else* statement is corresspond to a second *if* statement.

So I rewrite it like this, but I got a warning.

```
if (1) { // Block contains only one statement; remove the curly braces.
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if (0) console.log(1);
}
else console.log(0);
```

Is there a option to avoid that warning? If so, please give me a hint. Thanks for reading. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Not a good way**, but work.

```js
if (1)
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if (0) console.log(1);
if(!1) console.log(0);
```

Comment: Let's just use curly braces, if only to prevent unreadable code :) (no offense)

Comment: @Kokodoko I am totally in favor of using curly braces, but if if you want to remove such type of warning then only use above.(That's why I written _not a good way_)

Comment: Thanks for your idea ! :)

Comment: @Kokodoko I just don't use curly not to make code longer vertically, because in my opinion, that's also issue about readable code. I think a readable code is most important too, but thanks for your opinion !

Answer (score 1):

I ran the code you wrote first and it worked just fine. Although I agree that curly braces will make it more readable. I substituted true and false for your first if statement to make sure both the if and else are working properly and they are.

```
let myVar = false;

if(myVar) 
 for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
  if(myVar) console.log(1);
else console.log(0)
```

Here's the same code with curly braces. It makes it longer, but easier to read.

```
let myVar = false;

if(myVar) {
 for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if(myVar) {
    console.log(1);
  }
 } 
}
else {
 console.log(0)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I get '0' if myVar is false. If you change myVar to true, you'll get '1' printed to the console 10 times.